# adding tuples to a pandas database python

Tags: python, pandas, database, csv, for-loop

The function below prints out all the possible combinations of `Lower, Upper, number` each combination is printed out to a csv file for each iteration in the for loop. The values of the element are of type tuple and it is saved in csv file as `"(2.0, 2.0, 70)"` I want to print to the csv file without the quotation marks like this : `(2.0, 2.0, 70)` how would I be able to do that.

```
Lower = [round(x * 0.5,1) for x in range(4,23)] 
Upper = [round(x * 0.5,1) for x in range(4,23)] 
number = [round(i,1) for i in range(70, 400)]    
list_set = [Lower, Upper, number]
for element in itertools.product(*list_set):
    Output_Q1= [element]
    dataframe_Output_Q1 = pd.DataFrame([Output_Q1])
    dataframe_Output_Q1.to_csv("STDOutputs_Q1.csv", index=False, mode='a', header=False)
```

Output:

```
"(2.0, 2.0, 70)"
"(2.0, 2.0, 71)"
"(2.0, 2.0, 72)"
```

Expected output:

```
(2.0, 2.0, 70)
(2.0, 2.0, 71)
(2.0, 2.0, 72)
```

Comment: I can think of 50 things I don't like about how you are going about this... but you can solve your problem by changing this => `pd.DataFrame([Output_Q1])` to this => `pd.DataFrame(Output_Q1)`

Comment: Or not.  Nevermind, you wanted it to look like `(2.0, 2.0, 70)`  I gave you `2.0, 2.0, 70`.  I have realized that this is an XY problem.  I don't wan to be spending time solving Y when you should really be focused on solving X.

Comment: For a reference on what I mean by [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use tuples instead of array? I tried with array and that works fine.

Comment: Array gives me  `[2.0, 2.0, 70]` I would still prefer it rather than the `"(2.0, 2.0, 70)"`, however i would just like to have `(2.0, 2.0, 70)` if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is possibly easiest to not use dataframe's `to_csv` here at all, e.g. you can try

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
Lower = [round(x * 0.5,1) for x in range(4,6)] 
Upper = [round(x * 0.5,1) for x in range(4,6)] 
number = [round(i,1) for i in range(70, 72)]    
list_set = [Lower, Upper, number]

with open("STDOutputs_Q1.csv",'a') as f:
    for element in itertools.product(*list_set):
        f.write(str(element) + '\n')
```

and the file looks like this,

```
(2.0, 2.0, 70)
(2.0, 2.0, 71)
(2.0, 2.5, 70)
(2.0, 2.5, 71)
(2.5, 2.0, 70)
(2.5, 2.0, 71)
(2.5, 2.5, 70)
(2.5, 2.5, 71)
```